# Borland C++ Builder 6 TPrinter component having compatibility problems with PCL6

Tags: c++, printing, c++builder

I'm working in a project that (thanks to heritage issues) is done in Borland Builder C++ 6, a quite old IDE from 2002.

A problem I and previous developers had faced is that the TPrinter component that comes with BBC++6 is quite old and seems to have some compatibility issues with HP's PCL6. For now it's possible to use it only when a printer get PCL4 and my team is worried about future printers where PCL4 may not be acceptable anymore. The previous developer did quite an effort in trying to use PCL6 with Builder's component with no success. To be more specific, the error report from previous team members is:

> The Builder component doesn't work  well with printers using PCL6. It doesn't respect the Fonts orientations, some things become disoriented in the window.

My question is: which is the best way to solve this problem? Particularly I'ld be happy to find a patch or something from Borland making TPrinter compatible with PCL6, but other solutions may be welcomed. I'ld like to avoid having to create my own component or a particular printer class. Changing the IDE is not a viable solution, but including a compatible library is fine.

I'm glad for any help.

Momergil

Comment: Backwards compatibility doesn't really cost a printer manufacturer much to leave in, do you really think there's a risk that PCL4 will be dropped?

Comment: I suggest you search the web for PCL4 to see if it will be dropped.  My understanding is that PCL4 is enrolled or a subset of PCL6.

Comment: `TPrinter` does nothing that would affect PCL4 or PCL6 support. It calls GDI functions in the WinAPI, and those functions communicate with the printer driver directly. You're looking in the wrong place; `TPrinter` is not the problem. (You have the source code for it in the `Printers.pas` unit, which is the Delphi VCL wrapper used in C++ Builder; see for yourself.)

Comment: Well @MarkRansom and Thomas, I never searched about PCL4 details to see if it's a subset of PCL6, but a quick search in Wikipedia's article about PCL shows that PCL6 does have quite a difference from previous versions, including therefore PCL4, which means it's not that simple. Besides, one can notice that PCL6 is definitively a improvement, so it would be better to use it even without a dropping "threat".

Comment: @KenWhite, I will not disagree with you who seems to know about this much more than me, but I cannot defy empirical evidence ;) I just asked one that was dealing with the problem at the time and his report was: "The Builder component doesn't work  well with printers using PCL6. It doesn't respect the Fonts orientations, some things become disoriented in the window". (Note: question edited and improved).

Comment: If what @KenWhite says is true (and I have no reason to doubt it) then the problem will be with your printer driver, not with `TPrinter`.

Comment: As I said, you *have the source code* for `TPrinter`, in `Printers.pas`. You can see exactly what it does for yourself. :-) It does absolutely no printing or anything else; it exposes a `TCanvas` (in `Printer.Canvas`) that is used to produce all output. `TCanvas` is in the `Graphics.pas` unit, which uses GDI functions to do all output. There's absolutely nothing `TPrinter` does that bypasses the printer driver. The retrieval of fonts is done in `TPrinter.GetFonts`, which uses the Windows API `EnumFonts`, passing in the printer's HDC (again, standard WinAPI calls).

Comment: Could you give a minimal but complete working example of code that gives incorrect output on a PCL6 printer but works fine on a PCL4? As Ken White said it is nearly impossible for TPrinter/TCanvas to be at fault so it would have to be the printer driver (did you try different driver versions?) or your code....

Comment: @Eelke, I'll se about such a working example... The code that manifested the problem is actually quite big and part of a commercial application, so I'm not in position to copy and paste it here, but maybe a sufficient part will do the work :) Next monday I'll see about it...

Comment: I use TPrinter all the time, 10,000s of users and different printers, only problem I've ever had is related to floating point exceptions.  If that is your problem, update your question and I can provide an answer for that.